# How do you unlock the "Drift King" achievement in Rocket League?

Tags: achievements, rocket-league

The achievement description states that you have to:

> Perform a 180 powerslide with both the Cristiano and Spinner Wheels

I played a few games with each, and made sure to powerslide a lot. I tried 180º, slightly over 180º, and up to 360º+ slides with both wheels, without getting the achievement.

Are there any special requirements for a powerslide to count towards this achievement?

**Update:** I got the achievement after a seemingly unextraordinary power slide in a game a while after writing this question. The exact criteria for the power slides to qualify are still puzzling me though.

Comment: What format is this on, I don't recall seeing this as a trophy on PS4...

Comment: @djsmiley2k It's a DLC trophy for the Supersonic Fury DLC that was released today. http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/3679-Rocket-League/45-Drift-King

Comment: If you could, would you be able to take the Update section in your question and add it as an answer instead?

Comment: @Texenox Yes, but I still don't know exactly why I earned it then, and not another time. So I don't think it's good enough to be called an answer.

Comment: It seems fine enough, but I suppose you might be right. Maybe you could change up the question a bit to ask for that?

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it, you **have** to use the Takumi. I realized this after several tries with the Dominus.

I'm not sure if you do it with or without boost, someone should try doing it while boosting to confirm.

You're welcome though.

Answer (score 1):

Equip the Takumi car, then equip the spinner wheels. Go into a private match/online match, doesn't matter. Hold down hshift (the powerslide button) and drift in circles at least 2 times. Leave the game then equip the christiano wheels and do the same thing, this should get you the achievement!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this myself and just unlocked it. It seems like you need to do the powersilde while not boosting.

Answer (score -1):

I tend to turn 180° left every time, so I threw in a few rights and I got the achievement.